# How do I switch between tab screens by swipeing

Tags: rubymotion

I have 2 tab screens,

I want to swipe right to second tab screen

and  swipe left to first tab screen

But I don't know how to call open second tab screen in **handle_swipe** method

Any idea ? Thank you

## AppDelegate

`ruby
    class AppDelegate
      def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
        @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
        @window.makeKeyAndVisible
        first_tab = FirstTabController.alloc.init
        second_tab = SecondTabController.alloc.init
        @tabbar = UITabBarController.alloc.init
        @tabbar.viewControllers = [first_tab, second_tab] 
        @tabbar.wantsFullScreenLayout = true
        @window.addSubview @tabbar.view`

## FirstTabController

```ruby

```
class FirstTabController < UIViewController
  def init
    if super 
      self.title = "First Tab"
      self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.imageNamed('FirstTab.png')
    end
    self
  end 

  def viewDidLoad
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
    @label = UILabel.new
    @label.text = 'First Tab'
    @label.frame = [[50,50],[250,50]]
    view.addSubview(@label)

    # right
    recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action:'handle_swipe:')
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    # left
    recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action:'handle_swipe:')
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)    
  end

  def handle_swipe(sender)

    if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
      p "Swiped right"
      # @secondary_controller = SecondaryController.alloc.init
      @secondary_controller = SecondTabController.alloc.init
      # self.navigationController.pushViewController(@secondary_controller, animated: true)
    end

  end

end
```

```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the gesture recognizer to the UITabBarController view, in which case you would need to subclass it and move the `handle_swipe` method to that controller.

If you try this route, I would also move the code that creates and adds the gesture recognizers into the `viewDidLoad` method of the `UITabBarController` subclass.

Comment: hi, i've already has a method __handle_swipe__ but don't know how to open the other __UIViewController__ here.what's the syntax? thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the workaround to get ti.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I finished it by setting **UITabBarController** as a global variable, then change its index on swipe event occurs.

Is there any better practice to achieve this ?

I thought use the global variable may not be a good idea.

But I don't know the alternative way.

```diff

```
--- a/ch_2/12_tabbars/app/first_tab_controller.rb
+++ b/ch_2/12_tabbars/app/first_tab_controller.rb
@@ -13,5 +13,22 @@ class FirstTabController < UIViewController
     @label.text = 'First Tab'
     @label.frame = [[50,50],[250,50]]
     view.addSubview(@label)
+
+    # right
+    recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action:'handle_swipe:')
+    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
+    # left
+    recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action:'handle_swipe:')
+    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft
+    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
+  end
+
+
+  def handle_swipe(sender)
+
+    if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
+      p "Swiped right"
+      $tabbar.selectedIndex =1
+    end
   end
 end
diff --git a/ch_2/12_tabbars/app/second_tab_controller.rb b/ch_2/12_tabbars/app/second_tab_controller.rb
index 18ce656..8e718b0 100644
--- a/ch_2/12_tabbars/app/second_tab_controller.rb
+++ b/ch_2/12_tabbars/app/second_tab_controller.rb
@@ -13,5 +13,24 @@ class SecondTabController < UIViewController
     @label.text = 'Second Tab Controller'
     @label.frame = [[50,50],[250,50]]
     view.addSubview(@label)
+
+    # right
+    recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action:'handle_swipe:')
+    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
+    # left
+    recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action:'handle_swipe:')
+    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft
+    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
+
+
   end
+
+
+  def handle_swipe(sender)
+
+    if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
+      p "Swiped left"
+      $tabbar.selectedIndex = 0
+    end
+  end
 end
```

```